# How to remove specific element on List

Tags: java, list, linked-list

How to remove specific element on List?

```
...
java.util.List<Polygon> triangles = new LinkedList<Polygon>();
Point startDrag, endDrag, midPoint;
Polygon triangle;

....
int[] xs = { startDrag.x, endDrag.x, midPoint.x };
int[] ys = { startDrag.y, startDrag.y, midPoint.y };    

triangles.add( new Polygon(xs, ys,3));   
....

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
...
   startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
   for (Polygon p:triangles){
    if (p.contains(startDrag)) //Polygon has a 'contains(Point)' method
           remove (p.contains(startDrag));
   }
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to remove the object from the `triangles` list if you are currently iterating over it.  If you try to do so, you will trigger a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  Instead, what you should do is make a copy of the list and iterate over that, and when you get a hit, remove the item from the original:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
...
   Polygon[] triArray = triangles.toArray(new Polygon[triangles.size()]);
   startDrag = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
   for (Polygon p:triArray){
    if (p.contains(startDrag)) //Polygon has a 'contains(Point)' method
           triangles.remove (p);
   }
....
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove by object, such as removing a specific triangle from a triangle list, use List::remove(Object)

For the above purposes, you might want to use [List::listIterator()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator()), though.  Something like:

```
ListIterator<Polygon> it = triangles.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (it.next().contains(startDrag)) {
    it.remove();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just `List`/`Collection.iterator` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty, I dug it - it's the system thread from the Mouse Clicked being identified as not the creator of the java.util.Thingamabob ( a new data structure to be released tomorrow )

Despite documentation, in alignment with common sense, what the thing does actually is see that the thread from MouseClicked is not the Thread that created

`java.util.List<Polygon> triangles`

using something on the order of Thread ID or such as naming of threads go and then throws from deep within the JVM an exception ( sets the exception flag on the C side ) then returns leaving you with no functioning exception.getMessage() .....

You can implement copy semantics and the original version will work, does some bit-twisting on your brain but it works.

Comment: it's pretty deep, I have not had good reliability trying to answer these but what I was trying to say was to note for the reader that "Concurrent Modification Exception" was not implemented as I would think - rather than detecting two threads of which one does a remove() what had been done was to set the exception flag in the jvm solely on the basis that the thread attempting a remove() was not the thread that had created the java.uti.Collection. A button working from a system event thread could not modify even though synchronization semantics were observed.